# Set textbox width for appropriate iPhone version

Tags: iphone, textbox, resize

I write my first iOS application and I read many tutorials about how to handle pictures for different screen sizes of vaious iPhone version.
But how can I handle the size (width) of textbox which is tied with the background image (the image is changed by izs name for the relevant iPhone version, but the textbox width)?

I hope that bunch of if statements in code isn't the only way..

Thank you

Comment: I have answered it for text fields but you can apply the same auto sizing rules to any control button, image,etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're setting up the textbox in Interface Builder, check out the Size helper (in the right-hand panel, this is the tab marked with a ruler icon), and look at the image labeled "autosizing".  You'll see a box containing two arrows (vertical and horizontal), surrounded by four brackets (to the left, to the right, above, and below).  The arrows ("springs") represent the dimensions of the textbox itself - if they are solid, the textbox will adjust its size to fit a larger screen.  The brackets ("struts") represent the margins around the textbox - if they are solid, the textbox will maintain its position relative to the corresponding screen edges.  Each of these arrows and brackets can be toggled on and off by clicking.

For more, http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#recipes/xcode_help-interface_builder/articles/UnderstandingAutolayout.html.

Comment: I agree with your explanation but he needs first to disable auto sizing so he can find this options.

Answer (score 1):

select the story board or the xib file you are working on then uncheck "Use Autolayout" check box. as shown below.

[image]

after that you can control the width of the text box by selecting the textfield by selecting it then double check this configurations as shown in the next image.

[image]